# Emacs: auto-complete-mode on but no auto-suggestions showing (Emacs lisp mode)

Tags: emacs, autocomplete

I'm puzzled as to why nothing pops up (in Emacs lisp mode) when I begin typing a function name.  For example, after typing `(def` on a new line, I would assume that auto-complete should be showing me a alist of options which includes `defun`.  Am not sure how long the default delay is, but I waited for a few seconds and nothing happened.  Any suggestions?

Details regarding my installation process:

- Installed using `package-install` via Melpa
- Added the following two lines to my `init.el` file:

  `(require 'auto-complete-config)
  (ac-config-default)`
- Confirmed that `load-path` includes the folder containing the `.el` files associated with `auto-complete`.  (I have it set-up to recursively add all folders under `path/to/my/.emacs.d/`.)
- Confirmed (via `describe-variable`) that ac-dictionary-directories includes the correct directories when Emacs starts up.  As reference, it includes the following two directories:

  `ac-dictionary-directories is a variable defined in 'auto-complete.el'.
  Its value is ("/home/dchaudh/Dropbox/dchaudhUbuntu/emacs/.emacs.d/elpa/auto-complete-20140824.1658/dict")`
- Confirmed that auto-complete-mode is on when I open my `init.el` file, which obviously triggers emacs-lisp-mode (I can see `Emacs Lisp` in my mode line).  The following is included in the summary of active modes (i.e., via `describe-mode`):

  `Global-Auto-Complete minor mode (no indicator)
  Toggle Auto-Complete mode in all buffers.
  With prefix ARG, enable Global-Auto-Complete mode if ARG is positive;
  otherwise, disable it.  If called from Lisp, enable the mode if
  ARG is omitted or nil.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a direct answer, but `company` works fine out of the box in emacs-lisp-mode, so you might want to try that one.

Comment: i couldn't get auto-complete to work for the life of me (even with a trimmed down init file).  i should have tried company a LOT sooner.  also, helm + company is great.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, other modes (e.g. flyspell) can interfere with auto-complete operation.  (There is a workaround for slyspell built into auto-complete but you have to activate it in your. emacs file.)

I'd suggest trying it with an empty. emacs and then gradually adding parts of your configuration back in.  You should be able to find the problem that way.